# Search only posts (not pages) in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like that WP search engine search only posts (now it search posts & pages) - anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first, in the functions.php file in your theme, add this function:

```
function is_type_page() { // Check if the current post is a page
global $post;

if ($post->post_type == 'page') {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

Next, in your search.php file in your theme (where your search results are displayed, you want to add the following line right after the loop. It should look like this:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if (is_type_page()) continue; ?>
```